# principal axis theorem$4xy+x-5y-3=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

applying the principal axis theorem at $q(x,y) = 4xy+x-5y-3$ I get

- matrix $ A =\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$
- Eigenvalues $\lambda_1=2, \lambda_2=-2$
- Eigenvectors $v_1 = (1, 1)^t, v_2 = (-1, 1)^t$.
- rotation matrix $R = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

As you can see, $det(R) \not= 1$. There must be something wrong here, right?

Comment: What do you get the determinant to be, if not $1$? For me it is $$\Bigl(\frac1{\sqrt2}\Bigr)^2(1\cdot 1 - 1\cdot(-1)) = 1$$

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I got $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot (1\cdot 1 - 1\cdot (-1)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. I did not square the first factor! =)

Comment: x @Vazrael: when you scale the entire matrix, that corresponds to scaling each column separately. Since the determinant is linear in _each_ of the columns, we have $|\lambda A|= \lambda^n|A|$ where $n$ is the side length of the matrix.

Comment: @HenningMakholm That absolutely makes sense and I totally forgot the basics..! Thank you so much!